# Angular 8 - Cache HTTP Request using PublishReplay

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I can now cache 1 to 2 http request at the same time in same component and recache it after the cache expired, but when I try to add 1 more publishReplay() in a service, when I navigate to other component and back, it freezed for seconds, before it goes back.

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
if (this.reuse) {
  return this.reuse;
} else {
  return this.reuse = this.http.get(`${environment.url.userProfile}account-info`, this.userprofileKey()).pipe(
    publishReplay(1, 20000),
    refCount(),
    take(1)
  );
}
```

}

```
enter getUserInterests(): Observable<any> {
if (this.reuse3) {
  return this.reuse3;
} else {
  return this.reuse3 = this.http.get(`${environment.url.userProfile}interest`, this.userprofileKey()).pipe(
    publishReplay(1, 20000),
    refCount(),
    take(1)
  );
}
```

}

```
getEntitlementPlan(): Observable<any> {
if (this.reuse2) {
  return this.reuse2;
} else {
  return this.reuse2 = this.http.get(`${environment.url.entitlement}bau/subscription/current`, this.paymentKey()).pipe(
    publishReplay(1, 20000),
    refCount(),
    take(1)
  );
}
```

}

if I remove 1 publishReplay() from any from above. It works smoothly.

Comment: Can I know why you are caching with publishReply and refCount? Why not user 'shareReplay'?

Comment: Sorry im not yet that knowledgable of it , I also tried shareReplay, same behavior,  when I shareReplay 3services then When I revisited the component, it hangs, and sometimes my browser is not responding

Comment: You have written the above code in the service or component?

Comment: Thanks ill try it, btw, how am i suppose to control the expiration of cache and recache it when it expire? Ahhmm i did it in service.

Comment: Tried it, same behavior in publishReplay when I use it in 3 or more services at once using comnbineLatest or forkJoin. it hangs